# html AJAX call without return value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call, without expecting a return value. This is supposed to trigger a function remotely.
Following code is working, but returns this error in the browser console: `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

```
function clearTopData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      }
  };
    
  xhttp.open("GET", "cleartopdata", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

how am I suposed to open clearopdata, without expecting data?

Comment: If you don't care about the return value, don't assign to `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: It's interesting you're using GET but not expecting to get anything, however - can you just have the server return a status 200 response?

Comment: You can just ignore that console message. If you're not using the response, it's innocuous. It won't cause any error in the application.

Comment: could you not simply do: `fetch( 'cleartopdata' );`?

Comment: Anyone knows what circumstances trigger this error? I checked with fetch and Ajax and empty response doesn't do it for me.

Comment: @RoboRobok maybe the complete response is empty, not just the response body, i.e. not status code not headers, etc.

Comment: @sharkyenergy Could you try it with jQuery ajax `$.ajax()` ?